# Когда «наоборот» считается вводным словом?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Читала различные объяснения, но все равно не могу понять.
Пустое объяснение (без примеров) вряд ли пойму. Но примеры без теории для меня — контурная карта с единственным крестиком, обозначающим место встречи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда указывает на связь мыслей, обозначает  «напротив, в противоположность сказанному, ожидаемому».

Я часто вспоминал ее, когда ехал куда-нибудь, когда что-нибудь меня радовало или, наоборот, угнетало. Ю. Казаков, Осень в дубовых лесах. Я пел вместе с Лимончиком и видел, какое счастливое и красное лицо у Семенова, а у дедушки, наоборот, гордое и ехидное. В. Драгунский, Денискины рассказы.

Частица "наоборот" ставится в начале ответной реплики в значении «вовсе нет, совсем нет». Отделяется запятой или оформляется как отдельное предложение.

«Мы выпили за мою женитьбу, за мою невесту, за меня…» – «Вы пьяница?» – догадался Ипполит. «Наоборот. Именно поэтому я опьянел, у меня не оказалось необходимой подготовки». Э. Рязанов, Э. Брагинский, Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром.

В знач. «в обратном направлении, с противоположной стороны» или «совсем не так; в обратном порядке» не является вводным и не обособляется, это обстоятельство, а вводное не бывает членом предложения:

Для него было открытием, что Борисов любит Тургенева, а Соня Манжула – «Далеко от Москвы»; ему казалось, что должно быть наоборот. Д. Гранин, Искатели. Выслушай женщину и сделай наоборот.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_440&layout=item

Answer (score 3):

Это очень просто, если интересуют запятые:

"наоборот" не вводное, когда работает наречием и членом предложения в значении «в обратном направлении, с противоположной стороны» или «совсем не так; в обратном порядке».

Пример: *Выслушай женщину и сделай наоборот*.

В случае же вводного и частицы "наоборот" отделяется или обособляется.

*Я часто вспоминал ее, когда ехал куда-нибудь, когда что-нибудь меня радовало или, наоборот, угнетало*  - вводное.

*«Что ты такой печальный?» – спросил Эфэф. «Я? Наоборот, я очень веселый»* - частица (в начале ответной реплики).

**[источник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_440)**

---

Эврика! "Наоборот" не обособляется, если отвечает на вопрос КАК?

Answer (score 2):

**НАОБОРОТ**
**наречие** в значении ( *является членом предложения* ):
другою, противоположною стороною, с другой стороны;
совершенно иначе, не так, противоположно тому, чего ожидали, что хотели;
превратно, не так, как следует.

*Агния Барто*
**Мальчик-наоборот**

Все кладут
Сначала в рот
Бутерброд,
А потом
Едят компот.
**Он - всегда

Наоборот.**
...
Все остались
У ворот, -
Он собрался
В огород...
**Он всегда

Наоборот.**

-Ты всегда
Не как отряд, -
Октябрята
Говорят. -
**Раз ты всё

Наоборот,**
Ты ходи
Спиной вперёд.
...
- Отпустите! -
Он ревёт. -
Я хожу спиной
Вперёд!
**Я всегда

Наоборот.**

[Что такое Новый год?](http://iledebeaute.ru/gallery/2011/12/1/20982/29099/)

Что такое Новый год?
**Это все наоборот:**
Елки в комнате растут,
Белки шишек не грызут...

**НАОБОРОТ**
**наречие в значении вводного слова:**
в противоположность сказанному или ожидаемому.

*Вводные слова – это слова, формально не связанные с членами предложения, не являющиеся членами предложения и выражающие отношение к сообщаемому или его характеристику.

Вводное слов обычно (но не всегда) можно изъять из состава предложения.*

**Однако Володя, видя, как трудно мальчишке, совсем не ругался, а, наоборот, говорил нечто подбодряющее.** *Ю. Визбор,  Альтернатива вершины Ключ.*

**Овцы привыкли к тому, что человечек мог ночами выходить из квартиры на улицу по своим делам или, наоборот, очень поздно приходить с улицы домой.**
[Если мир наоборот](https://books.google.ee/books?id=NYHxCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82,&source=bl&ots=y2vDKuj5fT&sig=ZdeFfXOxubAjnsL9GbYPZAwT-W8&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDlaeYuIbTAhXQJSwKHRZTBrw4eBDoAQg0MAU#v=onepage&q=)

Как понять, что сотрудника пора повысить или, **наоборот,** уволить?

**Если правительство сделает эти исключения, то мы хотим повысить уровень обучения эстонскому языку до C1, так что это требование, наоборот, повысится.**  *Юри Ратас*

[вводные слова и сочетания](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)

Answer (score 1):

Эта тема интересна тем, что прочитав длинные и вроде бы правильные объяснения, понимаешь, что **умнее не стал и по-прежнему не знаешь, когда же обособляется "наоборот".** Всё дело в том, что **значения наречия "наоборот" и вводного слова"наоборот" различить  сложно**, поэтому мы попробуем найти другие признаки для определения функции слова.

**1) Позиция в предложении**

Наооброт – наречие, оно обычно относится к глаголу и стоит после глагола:  поступить наоборот  – это поступить совершенно иначе, противоположно тому, что нужно или что ожидается.

Что касается вводного слова  "наоборот", то оно  располагается в предложении свободно и не вступает в синтаксическую связь с другими словами, например: Неудача его не обескуражила, а даже, **наоборот,** вдохновила.

**2) Названные противоположные ситуации**

Но позиция – это даже не  главный фактор, по которому можно вычислить вводное слово "наоборот". Главное – **это наличие ДВУХ УЖЕ НАЗВАННЫХ противоположных ситуаций,** которые как раз и противопоставляются друг другу с помощью вводного слова "наоборот, например":

Ты меня **не слушаешь**! – Наоборот, **слушаю** очень внимательно.

Ты всё делаешь наоборот!  Сегодня я просила **прийти пораньше**, а ты, наоборот, **задержался**.

Возможно, эти простые примеры позволят Вам разобраться с этой темой.