# Обособляется ли в данном предложении слово "наоборот"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

"Женя сказал,  что девушка вовсе не красивая, а мне наоборот понравилась её внешность."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В этом предложении слово "наоборот" можно изъять (смысл от этого практически не изменится).
2. "Наоборот" в предложении имеет такое значение: напротив, в противоположность сказанному, ожидаемому.
   Имеются два противоположных мнения: кому-то нравится облик девушки, а кому-то – нет.
3. Делаем вывод: это вводное слово, требует обособления запятыми.
4. Точка должна быть после кавычек.

**"Женя сказал, что девушка вовсе не красивая, а мне, наоборот, понравилась её внешность".**
[**НАОБОРОТ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_440)

Некоторые объяснения и примеры можно посмотреть и на нашем сайте:
[Когда «наоборот» считается вводным словом?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431038/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за исправление! Получается, что  точка в прямой речи всегда ставится после кавычек?

Comment: Совершенно верно. **§ 199. Перед закрывающими кавычками не ставятся точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие и тире. Все эти знаки ставятся только после кавычек.**  http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp