# Запятая в предложении с сочетанием «и наоборот»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Нужна ли тут запятая?
Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить подробно, почему она здесь нужна и нужна ли?
Я читал в справочнике сайта *Грамота.ру* страницу по поводу этого сочетания, но, если честно, мало что понял и не вижу разницы между предложениями, которые там даются в качестве примеров.

[**И НАОБОРОТ,** *союз + наречие*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_237)

***То, что не нравится Вам, может нравиться сотням игроков(,) и наоборот.***

Comment: Здесь есть ответ. Думаю, все поймёте. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431038/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: Серж, а по ссылке не этот вариант разбирается. Здесь у нас сочетание И НАОБОРОТ в конце предложения, и для него есть специальное правило. И вот это правило надо применить к заданному предложению.

Comment: А если такое предложение: Что-то может нравиться вам, но не сотне игроков(,) и наоборот.   Здесь вроде бы не нужна запятая. А вы как думаете?

Comment: @Sharon По-моему, всё очевидно, всё точно так же: запятая нужна.

Comment: Спасибо. Но здесь же можно НЕ ПЕРЕСТРАИВАТЬ предложение, а заменить только словосочетание: Что-то может нравиться сотне игроков, но не вам ИЛИ вам, но не сотне игроков.  Тогда запишем: Что-то может нравиться сотне игроков, но не вам или наоборот.  Союз ИЛИ одиночный, запятая тоже не нужна. Можно так записать? Вы согласились с тем, что правило у Грамоты не идеальное, а вы не могли отредактировать у них первую фразу: "Если слова «и наоборот» замещают собой ЧЛЕН ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, запятая перед союзом не ставится". Чем заменить "член предложения"?

Comment: @Sharon Ну не-е... с ИЛИ звучит не очень (и замены вы не любите:)), а запись вообще мрак: запятую всё равно хочется поставить, т. к. после союза идёт предложение, хоть и напрочь неполное (здесь вы возразите, что так можно сказать и о "бытовой/мыслительной"). Мне кажется, что всё дело в союзе И, и замещает что-либо не сочетание "и наоборот", а только "наоборот". Написать "Легко принять мыслительную действительность за бытовую **и** бытовую за мыслительную" мы можем, а с вашим примером, думаю, что нет, надо так: "Что-то может нравиться вам, но не сотне игроков, **и** сотне игроков, но не вам".

Comment: Не влезло. С грамматической точки зрения нормально (ССП, после союза, как уже сказал, сильно покрыженное, неполное предложение ), но "по-нерусски" это. О, а сейчас подумал, что если написать всё полностью: "Легко принять мыслительную действительность за бытовую **и** легко принять бытовую действительность за мыслительную", то союз будет соединять однородные сказуемые, то есть всё получается. И спасибо вам большое – решил спросить обо всём этом Грамоту.

Comment: Misha, и вам спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: А Вам спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы понять, ставится запятая перед «и наоборот» или нет, нужно определить, **что** замещает это сочетание.

Рассмотрим примеры по ссылке из вопроса.

*Легко принять мыслительную действительность за бытовую и наоборот [бытовую за мыслительную].

Так они говорили, то возвышая, то понижая голос, переходя с русского на греческий и наоборот [с греческого на русский].*
В этих предложениях меняются местами только отдельные члены предложения, а «и наоборот» замещает повтор.

> Если слова «и наоборот» замещают собой член предложения, запятая перед союзом не ставится.

*Кто произносит при мне слово «воображение», тот вместе с тем произносит и слово «женщина», и наоборот [кто произносит при мне слово «женщина», тот вместе с тем произносит и слово «воображение»].

Но – вот, всё не удается, – он на воле, она в тюрьме, и наоборот [он в тюрьме, она на воле / она на воле, он в тюрьме]!*
Здесь уже мы не просто меняем местами отдельные слова. После «и наоборот» или вместо этого сочетания, чтобы был понятен смысл, нам нужно произнести целые предложения.

> Если слова «и наоборот» замещают собой не член предложения, а целое предложение, то перед союзом ставится запятая.

Предложение из вопроса:
***То, что не нравится Вам, может нравиться сотням игроков, и наоборот [то, что нравится Вам, может не нравиться сотням игроков***  или  ***то, что не нравится сотням игроков, может нравиться Вам].***
«И наоборот» замещает всё предложение, "переворачивает" его. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Да, запятая поставлена верно (плюсик от меня),  но правило у Грамоты, как мне думается, нуждается в пояснении. Члены предложения должны стоять рядом,  вот что важно, тогда запятую не ставим. А это предложение можно записать так; То, что не нравится сотням игроков, может нравиться вам. Структура остается, меняем местами только члены предложения (вам и сотням игроков). Но они стоят не рядом.

Comment: Да, можно составить по-разному, в том числе меняя местами только члены предложения. Но смысл запятой в том, что вместо "и наоборот" мы не можем произнести/записать часть. Об этом и говорится: "и наоборот" замещает целое предложение (с противоположным значением).

Comment: Цитата  из Грамоты с примерами: «Если слова «и наоборот» замещают собой член предложения, запятая перед союзом не ставится. Легко принять мыслительную действительность за бытовую и наоборот. Так они говорили, переходя с русского на греческий и наоборот». Но в примерах «и наоборот» замещает сочетание, а не один член предложения. Я помню, мы обсуждали здесь эту тему недавно, но я не нашла этот материал (кажется, там тоже не было все гладко). И я, прочитав статью из Грамоты, начала в заданном предложении переставлять члены предложения, и все получилось))  Так что, запятую не надо ставить?

Comment: А вот примеры у Грамоты с запятой: (1) Кто произносит при мне слово «воображение», тот вместе с тем произносит и слово «женщина», и наоборот». Здесь члены предложения можно переставить. (2) Но – вот, всё не удается, – он на воле, она в тюрьме, и наоборот! А вот в этом предложении всю структуру предложения надо переделывать. Вот может человек по таким правилам разобраться в новой для него теме, если я в известной мне теме начинаю сомневаться.

Comment: @Sharon Я не говорю, что правило на Грамоте идеальное, а отвечаю, как его следует понимать, исходя из запроса Миши. Так вот, неважно, что мы переставляем, главное то, что в сложных предложениях вместо (или после) "наоборот" не получится добавить только часть с отдельными членами, нужно сказать или написать целиком. Грубо говоря, запятая является грамматической. Без неё пишем: *"Так они говорили, переходя с русского на греческий **и** с греческого на русский"*, в сложном случае с ней: *"Кто произносит А, тот произносит Б, **и** кто произносит Б, тот произносит А"*.

Comment: ОК. Если Миша разберется теперь в правиле, то прекрасно. Я же говорила именно о том, что правило у Грамоты сформулировано не вполне корректно. А исправить его, как мне кажется,  можно так: Если слова «и наоборот» замещают собой словосочетание из членов предложения, запятая перед союзом не ставится.

Answer (score 4):

**Комментарий**

Спасибо, Александр, за внимание к теме. Я тоже еще подумала, и вот что получилось.

**Вариант редактирования**

Если слово «наоборот» замещает собой **член предложения**, то запятая перед союзом И не ставится. Обычно **такой член предложения** представляет собой **предложное сочетание двух предметов/признаков**, которые можно поменять местами. Тогда одиночный союз И связывает **две предложные группы** как однородные члены.

**Примеры:**

**Вариант 1.**  Так они говорили, переходя **с русского на греческий** и **с греческого на русский**.  Так они говорили, переходя с русского на греческий **и наоборот** (с греческого на русский).

Союз И подходит хорошо.

**Вариант 2.**  Легко принять **мыслительную действительность за бытовую** и/или **бытовую деятельность за мыслительную**. Легко принять мыслительную действительность за бытовую **или** **наоборот** (бытовую деятельность за мыслительную).

Здесь уже больше подходит союз ИЛИ, так как предложное сочетание более сложное.

**Вариант 3.**  Что-то может **нравиться вам, но не сотне игроков** или **нравиться сотне игроков, но не вам** . Что-то может нравиться вам, но не сотне игроков **или наоборот** (нравиться сотне игроков, но не вам).

Вроде бы союз ИЛИ подходит нормально. Но замещается уже не предложная группа, а **глагольное сочетание**.

**Да, больше вопросов, чем ответов…**

**Примечание**

Интересно, что сочетание "или наоборот" встречается в текстах, но его выделяют отдельным предложением, например:

*Человек может быть мужчиной и иметь женскую психологию. **Или наоборот.** В моем характере, например, больше мужских качеств.* Святослав Егельский. Человек с фигурой контрабаса, 2019

*Живем по принципу: «Ты намедни, а я давеча». **Или наоборот**. Как без оценки пройденного приступать к следующему этапу?* Анатолий Салуцкий. Немой набат, 2019

Таким образом можно сделать **ТАКОЙ ВЫВОД, чтобы закрыть тему.**

Союз ИЛИ, очевидно, не используется в этом сочетании, корректно только "***и наоборот***".

Для отсутствия запятой нужны **явные признаки,** такие как наличие падежного управления для всего словосочетания, чтобы можно было **сделать замену**. Этот случай можно считать **исключительным** и ориентироваться на приведенные **примеры из Грамоты**.

В остальных случаях, а их большинство, лучше **ставить запятую**.

Comment: Да, я тоже хотел там, в тех комментариях, сказать, что именно **без глагола** плохо звучит. // Не понял это: "Здесь уже больше подходит союз ИЛИ, так как предложное сочетание более сложное". Не увидел разницы: везде та же структуру, те же предлоги.

Comment: Да, спасибо, свой текст я дополнила выводом. Думаю, что больше не стоит заниматься этой темой (решение выглядит формальным, без особого смысла).  В то же время интересно понаблюдать в реальных текстах примеры с отсутствием запятой.